# How to use JQuery easing to "uncover" an image on a menu bar

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-animate

I have a menu bar:

http://jsfiddle.net/EyFPB/8/

which has an image on the menu which I want to slide down to uncover:

```
.green{background:#6AA63B;
   background-image: url('http://images.dailytech.com/frontpage/fp__army_fish.jpg');
   background-position:bottom;
   background-repeat:no-repeat;}
```

With the CSS like this though, the image is visible when the menu is collapsed and slides down. I want the effect to show the solid colour block (green in the example) and slide down to show the image.

Can I do this with JQuery animate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple CSS solution, add a `background-position:0 50px;` to `.green`.

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EyFPB/11/)**

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.

You need to set a custom .subtext class for each button:

```
.subtextGreen{
    height:100px;
    margin-top:-7px;
    background-image: url('../images/home-btn.jpg');
    background-position:bottom;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

and then in the code:

```
            <li class="green">
                            <p><a href="default.aspx">Home</a></p>
                            <p class="subtextGreen"></p>
                        </li>
```

Comment: Take a look at my answer.